# generate urdf file for a wifibot robot?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I want to know how to generate urdf file for a wifibot lab robot.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60972/generate-urdf-file-for-a-wifibot-robot?/) by [bn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4703/bn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try googling around to see if someone has a urdf file already or there are several tutorials on how to create your own file.

I recently just went through this process for our arm, so I'm oh too familiar. These tutorials were really helpful to me:

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials

Specifically, the first one in section 1 gives a great explanations of things. Then all of section 2 is really great too. I **strongly recommend** reading through all of them before you start writing your own file because I got to 2.4 and it starts with "if you're sick of doing all this by hand, here's how xacro can help make your life SO much easier".

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1